# It's possible to disable camera light on mute video (WebRTC) in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I have P2P connection, where I sharing audio and video and I implemented toggle video feature (mute video) and I'm disabling and enabling video on toggle action, but light is not disabled, it's possible to disable light too?

Comment: How are you "muting" the video?
You have no direct control over the light, and it would be quite scary if you did.

Comment: localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop()

Comment: Funny... that seems to work for me, Chrome 63. Maybe check that you're muting the right track (video, not the audio)? Don't know if order is guaranteed, but track 0 was audio the few times I tried it.

Comment: Light is disabled when you mute the video track?